# How can i increase/decrease the decibel values of an audio file in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, cross-browser, media-player

Hi I am trying a web app, where i will be running the audio file. I want keep one slide bar which will have the scale of decibels (db). On moving the slide bar up and down, the db value gets changed and audio file has to run according to that db value.

Currently i am using the  tag in html5 to run the audio files in browser through media player. Is there any default function or API that serve my purpose or i need to read the sound file and write the logic to change the db value.

I would like to run this feature across IE, chrome, safari and firefox.

Please some one suggest me what is the right approach to achieve this.

Thanks & Regards,
Siva.

Answer (score 0):

**SEE EDIT BELOW!**

According to W3 - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#effective-media-volume - it is possible to do this quite easily.

Using an audio tag, such as:

```
<audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Using JavaScript, you can do:

```
audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
audio.volume = 0.5; //half of original value
//0 = nothing
//0.5 = half of maximum
//1 = full volume.
```

Since you want to add a slider, using jQueryUI, you could add a slider with some slideStart/slideEnd events and then set the volume accordingly.

I hoped this helped ;)

**Edit:**

After reading again that you want *decibels*, **not** volume, I realised that what you want is not possible. It's extremely hard - if not impossible - to change the decibels of an audio file in HTML5. This is because:

1. The volume of the original file will always have a different decibel, and it's not possible to tell the amount of decibels in a file.
2. There are always hardware limitations, and there comes a point where you can't raise decibels.

Comment: Hi Riftes, thanks for your comments. My web app has to run on different platforms like Android, Windows ans IOS. With your inputs i decided to go with native way of coding in each OS. Thank you once again for your help.